# How to set navigation bar background color across all scenes

Tags: ios, swift

I have a tabbed view with 5 tabs. Also I have a navigation bar and with the following code I change its background color:

```
//Change navigation colors
viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
viewController.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Every tab has its own view controller, so instead of putting the same code in the `viewDidLoad()` method, I created a class `UIHelper` that has a static method `setupNavigation(viewController: UIViewController)`. So <strike>in every viewController in the `viewDidLoad()` method I just call the method</strike>:

```
UIHelper.setupNavigation(viewController: self)
```

Is there an easier way to change the global color of the background of a navigation bar?

I'm using Swift 4.

**Edit**: Actually I have one `MasterViewController` and every view controller of the tab extend it. So `UIHelper.setupNavigation` is called in `MasterViewController`'s `viewDidDLoad()`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> You have many ways to do that:
>   **First**
>   Create a **superViewController** and all other view controllers inherit this one:

```
import UIKit

class SuperViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

> **Other view controllers like that:**

```
class ViewController: SuperViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var pageVC: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

> **Now you don,t need to set navigation color in application only use Inherit superViewcontroller in every view controller. You can add all common methods which you are going to follow in every controller.**

**Second way to do that**

```
///Common NavigationController for every controller used in application
class NavigationController: UINavigationController {

    // MARK: - View Lifecycle
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.red
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}
```

> > **Use this navigation controller in everywhere in you app. When you need 
> >      navigation controller then give this class in the navigation controller.**

Comment: Yeah, I have a MasterViewController and `UIHelper.setupNavigation(viewController: self)` is put in its `viewDidLoad()`. I guess the other answer suggest "more global" & "accurate" way of doing this. I'm going to read more on that. Thank you for you answer

Comment: Please use common navigation controller in your application. I have updated my answer. Please have a look

Answer (score 6):

You can use the navigation bar proxy class (which forward settings to all navigation bars), for example run this in AppDelegate's method didFinishLaunchingWithOptions :

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.orange
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
```

Comment: This answer is related to the navigation bar, not to the status bar.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you one more way to do that. I think it is more universal and flexible. 
So I suggest you just subclass of `UINavigationController`. You can have as many implementations as you want in project. You can init this class from code or just set proper class in `Storyboard` file as well.

```
import UIKit

class CustomNavigationController: UINavigationController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Change navigation colors
        self.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
        self.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white
        self.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white]
    }

    //this method allow you to ask each controller for status bar style in navigation stack
    override var childViewControllerForStatusBarStyle: UIViewController? {
        return self.topViewController
    }

}
```

In your view controller class you should override this property as well

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override var preferredStatusBarStyle: UIStatusBarStyle {
        return .lightContent
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

For support for Dark mode and swift5 use this in AppDelegate:

```
 func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

 UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: .green]
    
    if #available(iOS 13.0, *) {
        if UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
        } else {
            UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
        }
    } else {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = .white
    }

...
return true
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below codes are working for iOS 15 *

```
if #available(iOS 15, *) {
    // Navigation Bar background color
    let appearance = UINavigationBarAppearance()
    appearance.configureWithOpaqueBackground()
    appearance.backgroundColor = UIColor.yourColor
    
    // setup title font color
    let titleAttribute = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 25, weight: .bold), NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.yourColor]
    appearance.titleTextAttributes = titleAttribute
    
    navigationController?.navigationBar.standardAppearance = appearance
    navigationController?.navigationBar.scrollEdgeAppearance = appearance
}
```